# Array.join() with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I use `Array.join()` function with condition

For example:

```
var name = ['','aa','','','bb'];
var s = name.join(', ');
```

The output is: `', aa, , ,'bb',`

I want to add a condition that will display only words that are not empty: `"aa, bb"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove empty elements from array and then use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on filtered array.

```
arr.filter(Boolean).join(', ');
```

Here, the callback function to `filter` is Boolean constructor. This is same as

```
// ES5 equivalent
arr.filter(function(el) {
    return Boolean(el);
}).join(', ');
```

As empty strings are falsy in JavaScript, `Boolean('')` will return `false` and the element will be skipped from the array. And the filtered array of non-empty strings is joined by the glue.

```js
var arr = ['', 'aa', '', '', 'bb'];
var s = arr.filter(Boolean).join(', ');

console.log(s);
```

You can also use [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces from the string.

```
arr.filter(x => x.trim()).join(', ');
```

Comment: I suggest explaining more about what's happening in both cases (and providing an ES5 version of your second example).