# Use .join() with callback condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the situation, I'd like to join each elements of an array depending on a condition. I imagine something like a combinaison of `join` and `reduce` functions, e.g. :

```js
const SEPARATOR =  ' ';
const array = ['I', 'am', 'coding'];

// my imaginary function (this does not work voluntarily, only for the example)
const output = array.join((previous, current) => {
    // when the function return true, it joins previous with current on the same index, else not
    return (previous + current).length < 6);
}, SEPARATOR);

console.log(output); // expected output : ['I am', 'coding']
```

To be clear, what I'm asking here is is there a way to achieve that with existing logic (for example, using a function similar to `join`) without recreating a whole logic.

---

FYI I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486800/array-join-with-condition) but does not answer mine, since the goal was only to remove `undefined` values.

Comment: I don't think this is a filter, although the output you want is shorter than the input you want to keep all of the elements. It's not really a join either, though, as you want an array not a string as the output. Did you try applying reduce to this? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no I didn't, my question here is whether can I achieve that with existing logic, or do I have to create a custom one from scratch

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a good idea to aim for clarity in your code. Even if your imaginary function existed, would a future developer - including Future You - be able to understand what it's doing?

Instead, be explicit, and break the problem down.

```js
const SEPARATOR = ' ';
const THRESHOLD = 6;
const array = ['I', 'am', 'coding'];

const output = [];
let current = '';
array.forEach(item=>{
    if( current.length + SEPARATOR.length + item.length < THRESHOLD) {
        current += (current ? SEPARATOR : '') + item;
    }
    else {
        if( current) output.push(current);
        current = item;
    }
});
if( current) output.push(current);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You're right, I updated my post to be more explicit so that no one is confused about it. Also my question was not to recreate a whole logic, but thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Version with `reduce`:

```js
const array = ['I', 'am', 'coding'];
const SEPARATOR = ' ';

const result = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (acc.length === 0 || (acc[acc.length - 1] + SEPARATOR + val).length >= 6) {
        acc.push(val);
    } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1] += SEPARATOR + val;
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach with `forEach` and `join` methods.

```js
const merge = (arr, sep, max_length = 6) => {
  const output = [];
  let prev = [];
  arr.forEach((curr) => {
    const word = prev.join(sep);
    if (word.length + curr.length >= max_length) {
      output.push(word);
      prev = [];
    }
    prev.push(curr);
  });
  if (prev.length > 0) {
    output.push(prev.join(sep));
  }
  return output;
};

const SEPARATOR = " ";
const array = ["I", "am", "coding"];

console.log(merge(array, SEPARATOR));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could implement something like this using `.reduce()`. Starting with an empty array, get the last element and the proceeding elements using `.at()` and `.slice()`. Then, based on the result of the callback, either return the current array with the new joined text at the end, or append the current element without joining.

```js
const joinWithCallback = (array, callback, seperator) =>
  array.reduce((previous, current) => {
    const last = previous.at(-1);
    const rest = previous.slice(0, -1);
    if (callback(last, current)) return [...rest, last + seperator + current];
    return [...previous, current];
  }, []);

const array = ["I", "am", "coding"];

const joined = joinWithCallback(
  array,
  (previous, current) => (previous + current).length < 6,
  " "
);

console.log({ array, joined })
```